# Laravel Class 'Datatables' not found error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatables

I am developping an application where i retrieve data from Mysql database and show it using Laravel and Datatable, i keep getting this error:

```
"Class 'Datatables' not found"
```

I tried different versions of Datatables but none worked and i keep getting the same error.

Here is code:

```
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;
use Datatables;

class AjaxdataController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('student.ajaxdata');
     //http://127.0.0:8000/ajaxdata
    }

    function getdata()
    {
     $students = Student::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
     return Datatables::of($students)//error
            ->addColumn('action', function($student){
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are using the `Datatables` class? And are you using any plugin for Datatables?

Comment: Which datatable package you are using.

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

Comment: What package are you using to generate this DataTable?

Comment: Are you including a javascript library and trying to use it in php code?

Comment: I am not using yajra package just the standard datatables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to let php know where this class is located. To do this, add the following `use` statement to the top of your file:

```
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
```

Now you can use `DataTables` in your code. Also make sure you use the correct capitalization.

---

**Update:**
You need to actualy install the package before you can reference it. Take a look at the documentation on how to install this package: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master

Comment: "Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DataTables' not found"

Comment: You need to install the package first, I updated my answer.

Comment: Why do i need this package, isn't there a solution to this error ?

Comment: Laravel does not have an out-of-the box implementation for DataTables. So if you don't want to create the table manualy: yes, you need this (or any other DataTables) package.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables
```

Please run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall it. but this time use:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables:^10.*
```

or
(any one of them)

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"^10.3.*"
```

or

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"^10.*"
```

using the * will install the latest version.

Then in the composer.josn file, check:
if `"Yajra\\DataTables\\": "vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables/src"` available in the

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
}
}
```

like this example:
if not then paste `"vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables/src"` like the example.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Yajra\\DataTables\\": "vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables/src"
    }
}
```

then run: `php artisan list`
hopefully you will find datatables package.
Now enjoy the code..